# not getting the Menu Magento 2

Tags: magento2, menu

I installed this template http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_shop4u/default/ and i can't find my menu (categories names ) in the top menu.

How can i get them back ?

Comment: Do you see pages in menu? This theme probably have some settings.

Comment: no i don't see pages in the menu

Comment: I have a menu that i created in the beginning now that i installed this template i can't see my menu i tried ti buld anothe mega menu in th  stores config but no result

Comment: Any errors in setup or exeption? Any errors in browser console? Screenshoot of configuration of you menu? if you paste this in home page do you see anything <p>{{block class="Sm\MegaMenu\Block\MegaMenu\View" template="Sm_MegaMenu::megamenu-horizontal.phtml" theme="1" group_id="2"}}</p>

Comment: Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Sm_MegaMenu::megamenu-horizontal.phtml' in module: 'Sm_MegaMenu' block's name: 'megamenu\view_0'

Comment: Whats the name of this theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83616/discussion-between-bartzalas-and-developper-magento).